# Determining for which starting values a recursively defined sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recursion

while studying the topic of recursively defined sequences I stumbled upon the following problem which I got stuck with, it goes as follows. Let $(b_n)_n$ be a sequence for which the following recursion formula holds
$$b_{n+1} = \frac{b_n}{2} - \frac{1}{1+b_n}$$
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I now need to find every starting value for which this sequenced converges.

Now the first thing i did was to see if there were any fixed points, but to my dissapointment i couldn't find any. I don't know any other methode on how to start solving this problem, so if anybody could maybe give a tip on how to start with this problem or give a method for solving it it would be greatly appreciated :))

Comment: If there is no fixed point, can the sequence ever converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, suppose you're studying a recursion of the form $b_{n+1} = f(b_n)$ where $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Then taking limits on both sides gives, by continuity,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_{n+1} = L = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(b_n) = f(L)$$

so the limit, if it exists, must be a fixed point of $f$. So if $f$ does not have a fixed point, this sequence cannot have a (finite) limit. A simple example here is $f(x) = x + 1$.

In this case we have $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{1+x}$. The fixed point equation is $f(x) = x \Leftrightarrow x^2 + x + 2 = 0$, which has no real roots. So there are no fixed points, as you've said, and hence no starting value for which the sequence converges. (Strictly speaking $f(x)$ has a pole at $x = -1$ but this makes the analysis simpler rather than more complicated: if the sequence $b_n$ ever takes the value $-1$ then it's never defined afterwards.)

If there had been fixed points (for example, there are fixed points when $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{1+x}$), the next thing you'd need to do would be to compute the [basin of attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Basins_of_attraction) of each fixed point. In nice cases you can do this by playing around with derivatives.

Comment: It maybe a silly question, but what if the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous? Must the limit still be a limit point in this case?

Comment: No, the argument uses continuity so without continuity the argument fails. Although I think if $f$ fails to be continuous then it would be pretty difficult for there to be a limit.

Comment: oh okay, I think ik get it. Thank you very much for your help :))